# SSRS Hide row except for highest version

Tags: reporting-services

This seems like it should be really simple but I couldn't find anything while googling.

On my SSRS report I have a few rows that are duplicates except for a few values changes in later versions. Can't I just use an expression on the row visibility "Show or hide base on an expression" to say something like 
iif(Max(version), true, false)?

I just can't seem to get the expression right.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to show all rows and only show the first column(s) of the data set or do you want to hide an entire row where specific values are duplicated?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but maybe you want something like this **IIF(Fields!Version.Value = Max(Fields!Version.Value), true, false)**

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of the code proposed by @Energ1ser (but without the redundant Iif).  This does depend on the parent group having the correct scope.